# Send message to client from a thread using python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

The goal of this code is to handle with multiple clients, where each client can start and stop a timer.\

When a client run the "start" command, it starts a timer. When it runs "stop", the same timer is stopped.
Every second, the value of the timer is printed in the server, however it would be nice to return this value to the client.

Thus, **handle_client** is a simple function that reads the message from the client and pass to the **Message_Handler** to start the timer. Inside of the **Message_Handler** is defined the thread.

How can I send the chronometer time (value printed every second) to the client?

#### The server

```
import socket
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import time

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "127.0.0.1" #socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "exit"
CONFIRM_MESSAGE = ("Message Received.").encode(FORMAT)

class Timer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True

    def terminate(self):
        self._running = False
        delta_time = datetime.now() - self.start_time
        print("Chronometer Stop Time: ", delta_time)

    def run(self, conn):
        self.start_time = datetime.now()
        while self._running:
            time.sleep(1)
            if self._running:
                delta_time = datetime.now() - self.start_time
                conn.send(str(delta_time).encode(FORMAT))
                print("Chronometer: ", delta_time)


class MessageHandler(object):

    def read_message(self, conn, addr, msg):
        print(f"Address {addr}: Message: {msg}")

        if (msg == "start"):
            conn.send(("[STARTING TIMER]").encode(FORMAT))
            self.timer = Timer()
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.timer.run, args=(conn,))
            self.thread.start()

        elif(msg == "stop"):
            self.timer.terminate()
            return CONFIRM_MESSAGE

        else:
            return CONFIRM_MESSAGE

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"\n[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    mh = MessageHandler()

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
            return_msg = mh.read_message(conn, addr, msg)
            if(return_msg != None):
                conn.send(return_msg)

    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = socket.socket(family = socket.AF_INET, type = socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(ADDR)
    print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
    server.listen()  # We can use an argument that is an int and limitates the number of connections
    print(f"[LISTNING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")

    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
```

### The client

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "exit"
SERVER = "192.168.1.251"
SERVER = "127.0.0.1"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

connect = True
while connect == True:
    input_msg = input("message: ")
    send(input_msg)
    if(input_msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE):
        send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
        connect = False
    data = client.recv(64)
    print(data)
print("[SYSTEM DISCONNECTED]")
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I cannot send the time to the client. The conn.send inside the Timer.run

Comment: how is your client looks?

Comment: Now it is included in the main text.

Comment: your client never reads from the server while timer is running.

Comment: That's my problem, I would like to send a message with the clock time, to the client.

Comment: @nunodsousa georgexsh says the message IS SENT but the client doesn't ask to receive it because it doesn't call recv

Comment: Well, one of the things that I've tried was to put a recv in the client and I could get one clock time, however, it stops there. (I include the intent in the client code).